# How do marks interact with dual attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark

The specific example from last night involved a Demon Manipulator<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=3939)</sup> using his Deceptive Attack to attack both my paladin and an ally.  Would this violate the mark and trigger Divine Challenge<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=4)</sup>?

My DM felt that since the creature used one action to do the two attacks it was not violating the mark.  I disagreed as the action used states to make two attacks. The second attack did not include the paladin at all and should have triggered Divine Challenge in my opinion.

What is the correct ruling and why?

Comment: Some monster powers have been rewritten to handle this very case, "the monster makes one attack on two targets with separate rolls for each target". These types of attacks would not violate the mark.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The attacks granted by Deceptive Attack are considered individually for triggering the Paladin's Divine Challenge.

> The demon manipulator makes either two
>   claw attacks or two ray of
>   manipulation attacks

Each of the attacks made possible by the Deceptive Attack is a separate attack. This power grants action economy - do a pair of things that normally would each be standard actions, for the cost of a standard action.

This differs from a Blast or Burst which is both a single action and a single attack and so can be used to work around defender abilities such as the Paladin's Divine Challenge

Other attacks target multiple enemies explicitly on their target line. The attacks also do not trigger the defender's mark penalty as long as one of the targets is the defender. Such attacks are written along the lines: "Target: one or two enemies"

Answer (score 6):

Don't have the rules at the moment: it depends on the demon's Deceptive Attack wording.

Bursts and Blast attacks (even those performed through a weapon) don't trigger Divine Challenge if they include the Paladin. Their single attack rolls are simultaneous.

If a power says something like "*repeat the attack against the same or a different target*" or a monster's attack entry refers to another attack entry (like: "*The huge and ugly creature makes two claw attacks*"), then each attack is self-confined, and if any of these don't include the Paladin, Divine Challenge triggers.

Also, the marked condition, and the Divine Challenge power don't name the *action* term with regards on attacks that trigger their effects.