# Can a defender counter on a multiple attack power where only one attack includes her as a target?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark, attack, triggered-actions, defender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do marks interact with dual attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/how-do-marks-interact-with-dual-attacks)

Defenders usually have a power with a trigger like:

> **Trigger:**  An enemy marked by you makes an attack that does not include you as a target

Solo monsters and others often have powers that allow them to use an attack power repeatedly.
Example:

> Double Attack
>    **Effect**:  The sovereign panther uses claw twice.

So what happens if the first claw attack does not target the defender but the second claw does target the defender.  Can the defender respond with his trigger?

If a meta-multiple attack power only includes the defender in one of the attacks, does it allow the defender to use their trigger power?

Comment: See also my closed re-asking of the same question :)

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Ha, oh well.  It was hard to tell that it had already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, and that's the way we're playing in my campaign.

If the designers didn't intend it to go like that, I think they could have written the text as, for instance:

> **Trigger:**  An enemy marked by you *uses an attack power* that does not include you as a target

Comment: right, this is the important wording, if it's one attack with 3 targets that's fine, but if they are separate attacks with different targets each attack is subject to the Defender's mark.